# Why is Excel copying the formatting of previous cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have severeal rows that I have marked in red.

As I type in the cells of following rows, the formatting is copied.
I don't want this behavior, why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Excel copies the format if there are 3 rows above the current cell with the same format. One workaround is to fill in the row and then remove the formats you don't want. The following rows should be without the formats.

Added:
[This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/extend-formats-and-formulas-to-additional-rows-HP005229125.aspx) should work for you.

> You can turn this option off (or back on again) at any time:
>
> On the Tools menu, click Options.
>   - On the Edit tab, clear the Extend data range formats and formulas check box to turn automatic formatting off.
>   - To turn automatic formatting back on again, select the Extend data range formats and formulas check box.

Comment: There's no way to shut that off?
It's seriously annoying.

Comment: There might be, but I don't have Excel at home.

Comment: I'm using Office 2010, so this solution is not workable. The tool menu does not appear to exist.